# Trying to get my slide box to cover the entire page, but not cover my tabs at the bottom

Tags: css, ionic-framework

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPbQNZ)

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box class="my-slide-box">
      <ion-slide>cat</ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>dog</ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>rat</ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
    <div class="tabs" style="height:auto;">
      <div class="row"><div class="col" style="padding: 0">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive">
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

How can I make `my-slide-box` extend only until the `tabs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css `calc` for calculating the height of `.my-slide-box`.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/zrvOpm)

```
.my-slide-box {
  height: calc(100% - 77px); // 77px is the height of tabs
  background: green; 
}
```

Comment: O ok.  Thanks!  what about if the screen res is very high?  I am working with iphone 4 right now, but what about phone like LG G4 which came out this year which have 1440x2560 resolution?

Comment: It works. You can check [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) or [you can use](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) `vh` instead of percentage value.

Comment: thanks.  hey but one more thing.  in the code pen it works, but in my actual chrome the element is sized to 23% for some reason?  I have put in height: calc(100% - 77px); not sure what is going on?

Comment: Try to add `height:100%` to html and body.

Comment: Hi,  unfortunately it did not work.  I am wondering if there is something else from ionic css probably making issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97659/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-user1354934).